# In Mule extension using Mule 4.1.4., Is there a way to get information about the next operation in my operation?

Tags: java, mule

I'm creating a Mule extension using Mule 4.1.4..
Is there a way to get information about the next operation in my operation?

For example, in the following definition, I want to know that the next operation is vm:publish.

```xml
<foo:my-operation />
<vm:publish queueName="myQueue">
    <vm:content>#[payload.body]</vm:content>
</vm:publish>
```

And, in the following definition, I want to know that the next operation is http:request.

```xml
<foo:my-operation />
<async>
    <http:request method="GET" path="greet" config-ref="clientConfig"/>
</async>
```

I can get my operation information using ComponentLocation, but I don't know how to get the next operation information.

Comment: Why do you want to know that? Please describe the use case.

Comment: @aled, I provide a library to my customer. The purpose is to collect various types of information and execute pre-processing suitable for communication contents, by placing my operation before user communication operation. In addition, I don't want to prepare for each communication operation that the user uses.

Comment: That probably goes about the design of the runtime. Each component should be independent of the following ones.

Comment: I think you are right.
I temporarily use the ConfigurationComponentLocator obtained using @Inject and the ComponentLocation defined as an Operation parameter until an alternative is found, such as a library design change.

Comment: "such as a library design change.", I mean "such as **my** library design change."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible or should be attempted. I guess it goes against the expected usage of components in flows in Mule. The expectation of a flow is that you can change components in a flow as long as they agree on the data exchanged between them. This would introduce a coupling between components.

It would be better by making message processors for each use case and it probably it is easier.

Example:

```
<foo:my-operation-formatA />
<vm:publish queueName="myQueue">
    <vm:content>#[payload.body]</vm:content>
</vm:publish>

<foo:my-operation-formatB />
<async>
    <http:request method="GET" path="greet" config-ref="clientConfig"/>
</async>
```